# Javascript: Calling function in parent from iframe

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, parent

Hello StackOverflow community,

I was having a problem with my `<iframe>` and JavaScript. Let's say I have an index.html with an `iframe` in the body. Within the `index.html` I have this in the `<head>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertTest() {
        alert("Testing");
    }
</script>
```

In the iframe's `src="iframe.htm"` (The location is the same domain as index.html). Within that `iframe.htm` page I have:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.parent.alertTest();">Click here.</a>
```

The problem is it is not loading the alert and in Google Chrome returns the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'alertTest' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

I have tried `window.parent.alertTest();`, `window.top.alertTest();`, `top.alertTest();`, `parent.alertTest();` and nearly everything that came up on similar problems I searched.

It seems you are unable to call a function located in a non-iframe, from the iframe located within said non-iframe.

Please help!

P.S.  Essentially in the actual final outcome I'm trying to call a Lightbox open image function (Using slimbox because I am able to call the open image function with it from javascript rather than from a href).  I have also tried in this final outcome using the  target="_parent" property.

Answer (score 12):

Try defining your function like this:

```
window.alertTest = function () {
  alert("Testing");
};
```

...and calling it in the same way you have in the question ;-)

In a browser, everything in javascript is a child of the `window` object. When you define a function in the form `function funcName() { ... }` you are effectively defining a private method of the `window` object. This doesn't matter under normal circumstances, because all code is executed within the scope of `window`, so it has access to these private methods.

But when you try and access the `window` object from the outside (i.e. another `window` object, that of your iframe) you will not be allowed access to it. If you define the function in the form `window.funcName = function () { ... };` you are creating a privileged method, that is accessible from the outside but also has access to the private methods and properties (i.e. the variables in the script), so it will work when you try and call it from your iframe.

[Read this](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) if you want to know more about private/privileged members and their accessibility.

Comment: Why is this not the accepted and most upvoted answer? It works like a charm and comes with an excellent explanation

Answer (score 10):

use `parent.functionName`. Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1):

Write your function like this:

```
alertTest = function(){

  alert("Testing")

}
```

Then call it from iframe:

```
parent.alertTest();
```