# Change innerHtml From Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, html, document-ready

I'm attempting to change the innerHTML of a div from the ready function of an iframe's src. Code below. The innerHtml will not change, but the color works fine. Ideas on why this is happening and/or how to fix it?

Page

```
<html><head></head><body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/Import_Subprocess_Content/RAC_Connolly.js"></script>
<div id="importcontent" runat="server">
</div>
<iframe id="frametest" src="./AJAX/Import_Subprocess_Content/RAC_Connolly_ImportSession.aspx">

</iframe>
<div id="popup">FIRST TEXT</div>

</body>
```

Iframe src

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Utilities/Javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Javascript/Import_Subprocess_Content/RAC_Connolly.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        uploadComplete();
    });
</script>
end it!
```

js

```
function uploadComplete() {
    window.parent.document.getElementById("popup").innerHtml = "lala";

}
```

Testing in IE7 exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround you can try:

1. Transfer `uploadComplete` method to parent.

   ```
   function uploadComplete() {
      document.getElementById("popup").innerHtml = "lala";
      return false;
   }
   ```
2. Call this method in your iFrame

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       parent.uploadComplete();
   });
   </script>
   ```

Similar question: [Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function)

Comment: No dice. It changes everything except the innerhtml when I try different properties.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization issue. Correct syntax is

```
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = "HTML";
```

not

```
document.getElementByID("ID").innerHtml = "HTML";
```

I was following a fusion of c# and javascript maybe with a VB twist syntax due to switching languages so often. Stupid small errors, big problems.