# Can't access YouTube video through YouTube JS API inside of Google Chrome Extension, but can inside of JS Fiddle

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am attempt to understand the logic behind whatever trips the 'blocking' mechanism for YouTube's video playback.

Here I am attempt to play back a song which is blocked from embedded playback inside of a JS Fiddle. Observe that it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/E7B9C/17/

[image]

Now, I use the exact same code inside of my Google Chrome extension:

http://www.meomixes.com/ if you'd like to click to download extension.

http://www.meomixes.com/Test.crx for direct link to extension.

Observe that I cannot playback the same youtube video:

[image]

I was wondering what my debugging options were for this scenario. Does anyone have any ideas on what I should explore? I've tried requesting the following permissions in my manifest, but it did not have any effect:

```
"permissions": [
"http://*.youtube.com",
"https://*.youtube.com",
"http://*.google.com",
"https://*.google.com"
]
```

I've placed the full source of Test.crx here: http://www.meomixes.com/Test.zip
To load:

- Unzip
- Go to Google Chrome's extension page and enable 'Developer Mode'
- Click 'Load Unpacked Extension' and point to the unzipped directory.
- Observe that the video does not play back.

Last of note: The song plays happily in a Facebook post.

EDIT: I found this: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/UfESt2KdOdc?v=2&prettyprint=true for the video in question. It pairs with: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html.

Just building on the first response. Basically, there is a setting called 'syndication' which prevents from playing on 'external devices' such as TVs and Google Chrome Extensions.

Looking at ways to bypass this issue now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Youtube iframe implementation seems to block certain referring urls from displaying licensed content.

**The Problem**

These referring schemas didn't seem to work with the particular video you're testing with.

```
 chrome-extension://
 file://
```

It seems like content licenser, UMG, opted to prevent any plays from extensions or local files. An alternative is to avoid using videos that contain licensed content, but that's boring.

It's inconvenient but there is a workaround that will allow you to implement the iframe player into the extension. All Youtube cares about is that the the player is embedded on a page somewhere on the internet.

**Proxy Page**

Try replacing the iframe src in **popup.htm** with the jsfiddle result frame from your example and reload your plugin.

```
 <iframe width="200" height="200" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/E7B9C/17/show/"></iframe>
```

You should see the previously "unavailable" video playing now. Your extension now references a page you control on jshell.net. All Youtube knows is that you're calling their player from jshell.net.

**Controls**

Now that we have a player, you may notice that you don't have any of the Youtube controls available to you since you're now referencing your own iframe that's referencing the Youtube iframe and it's API. As if it weren't fun enough already, you now get to make your own iframe API to communicate from the chrome-extension to your iframe to Youtube's iframe!

Under normal circumstances a parent can set the child frame's window.location.hash and that frame watches and parses any changes that come through. The child then calls some callback in the [parent directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function) with some new information.

**Edit:** Instead of using window.location.hash, you could use HTML5's window.postMessage() instead and avoid having to deal with checking and parsing the hash continuously.

That should get you up and running.

Comment: This is a very detailed response. I will play with it when I have time, hopefully this evening. I hesitate because the YouTube content I wish to display is dynamic -- I wish to be able to load a video on demand while also bypassing the YouTube blocker.

I may just write an algorithm to find an identical video which is not content restricted, though. Unsure still which would be easier at this point in time. Thank you for your response! :)

EDIT: I am also wondering -- is it possible to spoof the referring URL s.t. it appears to not come from a Google Chrome extension? Doing reading about it now

Comment: I played with writing to document.referrer, but even as an extension it still seems to be read-only. You could use location.hash to pass the Youtube ID you want to play to the embedded iframe, have the iframe catch the id, and dynamically modify the embed.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted your answer for the research put in on your side. I went ahead and just wrote the logic to find a copy of the song. I chose this route because there are more ways to disable a song than just the embed issue. As such, it seemed appropriate to find a way that handled all the issues in one. Cheers man. :)

Comment: @SeanAnderson: You may also want to award him the bounty. Otherwise, he'll only get half. You have only 7 hours left.

Comment: @Truth, [**An answer accepted during the bounty period can automatically be awarded the full bounty at the end of the bounty period...**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067)