# Embed YouTube videos gives "Restricted from playback on certain sites" error on chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I get the error "This video contains content from UMG. It is restricted from playback on certain sites." when trying to play certain embedded YouTube videos in Chrome extension.

I'm using YouTube IFrame API.

All the code is inside the popup.

I've tested my code on Localhost, and didn't got the error.

Example for YouTube Video with the restriction issue: [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJC-subagTg).

I found a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971792/cant-access-youtube-video-through-youtube-js-api-inside-of-google-chrome-extens), but didn't understand how to bypass the restriction issues.

@Workman suggested that YouTube IFrame implementation blocks certain referring urls from displaying licensed content and proposed a solution, but I need a dynamic solution.

I would really appreciate any help I can get.

PS. I wouldn't like to avoid videos that contains license content.

Comment: Would a short "don't bypass licensing constraints" suffice here? If not, you can make a dynamic solution (potentially), but it requires a website you control, as per that question.

Comment: Lets say I have a website, how will this dynamic solution work?

I know that Sean Anderson solved it by "writing the logic to find a copy of the song". But I don't understand what it means.

Comment: this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001251/youtube-v3-api-know-if-the-video-is-avaliable-on-android-mobile-device/17004800#17004800

Answer (score 0):

> but didn't understand how to bypass the restriction issues.

you don't. The viewer may, if he uses a proxy or vpn and, sometimes, by changing the user agent.