# Iframe Get/Post Data from Parent

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe, get

is it possible to have an iframe read post-data or get-data from the parent frame?

example: if my current URL is www.site.com/parent_frame.html?url=www.frame.com/nav1/nav2/child_frame.html

would the frame embedded in the parent site be able to be set to load www.frame.com/nav1/nav2/child_frame.html.

I have access to both domains, however cannot use anything other than html and javascript on the parent page. the child page has access to PHP, javascript, HTML.

I am aware of the security risk of putting a URL in the get/post data and obviously the child would have validation to confirm that the URL is within the proper scope before loading, I just simply need some advice/direction on if this is possible.

Comment: Possible:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you: [Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function)

While this isn't setting anything in the GET/POST data it is a method to use JavaScript inside an iframe to access JavaScript within the parent frame/page.

Comment: ill read that over this weekend as a back-up plan if no get/post is available, if possible id like to use that as the framework is already basically in place (urls in get data of iframe, get-data based redirects, and other fun jazz)