# Call a javascript function from an iframe

Tags: javascript, events, html, iframe, slide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iframe Function Calling From Iframe to parent page javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function)

I have a JavaScript function written in my main page. It's a function that slides up the div "toggle" (with jquery).

This main page contains an iframe that is embedded into the div#toggle.

When I click on a link that belongs to the iframe I would like to execute the slide up function.

I put an onclick event on a link in the iframe (to trigger the function declared in my main page) but it doesn't work. Well, I'm not that surprised but I don't know how to make it work.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: You are going to have to post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.parent` to access the containing page:

```
window.parent.someToggleFunc();
```

Note that Javascript access between iframes like this are subject to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).