# How to get Iframe functions and variables from parent document using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe which will be called on clicking on a button. Now all i want is to get the javascript variables and function in the iframe from parent window. Can anybody help me out to get it.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iframe Function Calling From Iframe to parent page javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1639342/2256325 - if it doesn't help you please post a code example so we understand your question better.

Comment: Hi Sergio : That response is close but my problem is like that iframe is from other domain . In that case how can i get those elements?