# How can I call parent window’s function sb(frm) and pass parent’s form from child window?

Tags: javascript

I have the following script in the window that opened a current window:

```
function sb(frm){….}
```

How can I call parent window’s function sb(frm) and pass parent’s form from child window?
I want to do something like that

```
if(sb(parent.form)){…}
```

The code I tried

```
var zzz = window.opener.$("#frmevent"); 

if(sb(zzz))
    zzz.submit();
```

MY HTML:

```
<form action="app_editevent.jsp?nextlevel=1&" method=post onsubmit='return sb(this);' name=frmevent id='frmevent'>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iframe Function Calling From Iframe to parent page javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1):

The right tool to deliver messages between parent/child windows (iframe) is [*postMessage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) otherwise you're risking having your code detected as "problematic" from security perspective when the parent and the child are not located on the same domain.

Comment: They both are located on the same domain.