# run jquery script on page in iframe by onclick form another page

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have this index page with 2 iframes. In one of the iframes in the page I have some links:

```
<a href="home.html" target="content" onclick="run.slimmscroll(#anchor1);">Home</a>
<a href="home.html" target="content" onclick="run.slimmscroll(#anchor2);">Home</a>
<a href="home.html" target="content" onclick="run.slimmscroll(#anchor3);">Home</a>
```

The `home.html` is loaded into the "content" Iframe. Now I need to execute a Jquery script on the `home.html` when it is loaded. Here is the script:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function() {             
$('#scroll').slimScroll({    
start: $('#anchor1')
  });    
 });
</SCRIPT>
```

The idea is to get `home.html` to `#anchor1, 2, 3` and so on with smooth scrolling which it normally does on page load but I would like to do it with the `onclick()` from the other page.

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle showing what you're trying to do?

Comment: No I don't. Index page is very large.

Comment: I've worked with slimscroll a lot but I have no idea what you're trying to do ... try to explain it better.

Comment: @Joel_Blum, Standard I use #anchor1 in the link and when the home.html is loade into the iframe it goes to #anchor1 but it does not go smooth to #anchor1 so I want to execute the script on the page so it will smooth scroll to #anchor1 from the link. From another link (home.html onclick="run.slimmscroll(#anchor2) I would like to smooth scroll to #anchor2.

Comment: To simplify my question: I just need to execute a script on one iframed page from another iframed page with onclick()

Comment: Need to do somthing like this but not on the parent page but the iframed page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
onclick="window.parent.content.slimScroll();"
```

The syntax on the home.html would be:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">              
$('#scroll').slimScroll({    
start: $('#anchor1')   
});
</SCRIPT>
```