# parent div won't update after fancybox close

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a functioning Fancybox form that deletes data from MySQL. I wish it to refresh a specific parent page DIV upon closing.

The JavaScript involved:

```
function ajaxrequest(php_file, purpose, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, where) {
    var request = getXMLHTTP();     // call the function for the XMLHttpRequest instance

    // create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
    var the_data = 'purpose='+purpose+'&var1='+var1+'&var2='+var2+'&var3='+var3+'&var4='+var4+'&var5='+var5+'&var6='+var6+'&var7='+var7+'&var8='+var8;

    request.open("POST", php_file, true);           // set the request

    // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(the_data);     // calls the send() method with datas as parameter

    // Check request status
    // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            window.parent.document.getElementById(where).innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
}

function done_with_msg() {
    ajaxrequest('include/ajaxprocess.php', 'refresh', 'Messages', '',  '',  '',  '', '',  '',  '', 'content2');
    javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
}
```

In the Fancybox:

```
<button onclick="done_with_msg();">UPDATE</button>
```

Function `ajaxrequest` is separated because I use it (works perfect) in other areas of the site. For this issue I am deleting a message thread in the Message DIV and wish to refresh ONLY the Message DIV with the deletion completed.

Comment: is the fancybox opening as iframe? because you are closing as `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()` if so, the ajax call `ajaxrequest()` exists in the parent but not inside the iframe. If that is the case, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2161402/1055987

Comment: yes fancybox is opening as an iFrame. checked what you referred to and worked lke a charm. now post an answer so I can give you credit lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fancybox opening an iframe, the functions `ajaxrequest()` and `done_with_msg()` may not exist in the iframed page but in the parent page.

If that is the case, you have to call the function(s) in the parent page as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2161402/1055987) like :

```
<button onclick="parent.done_with_msg();">UPDATE</button>
```