# How to call parent window function from child window jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i just need to call function in parent window while user is focusing on child window.
i have this code in my parent window,

```
<html> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CallParent()
        {
            alert(" Parent window Alert");
        }
    </script>
    <body> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" NAME="My Window Name" title=" My title here " onClick=window.open("child.html","Ratting","width=550,height=170,0,status=0,");>Click here to open the child window</a>
    </body> 
</html>
```

and bellow code is in my child window,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
                window.opener.CallParent();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h2>This is Child window</h2> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

so..in this case i supposed that `CallParent()` will be fired just after child window is opened. but it seems to be not working.
can any one give me any hints to make this script to work, or any better way to do this.

Comment: Does window.opener contain an object or is it undefined? Are there any errors in console?

Answer (score 22):

Use this

```
window.parent.CallParent();
```

instead of

```
window.opener.CallParent();
```

`window.parent` holds a reference to the parent of the current window or subframe.

If a window does not have a parent, its `parent` property is a reference to itself.

When a window is loaded in an `<iframe>`, `<object>`, or `<frame>`, its parent is the window with the element embedding the window.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent

Comment: While this may solve the problem, you should provide some explanation to your answer and maybe also include a link to a resource where you can find more info about that.

Comment: Does it really work? I'm trying to use this approach to no avail - I'm getting the following error: window.parent.CallParent() is not a function...

Comment: this was working before but right now this not working in any browser please suggest another option

Comment: @RaviPatidar This only works if the parent and child windows are on the same origin. If they are on different origins, you can use [window.postMessage()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe) instead.

Answer (score 14):

Try something like below:

**parent.html**

```
<html> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.CallParent = function() {
            alert(" Parent window Alert");
        }
    </script>
    <body> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" NAME="My Window Name" title=" My title here " onClick=window.open("child.html","Ratting","width=550,height=170,0,status=0,");>Click here to open the child window</a>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
                opener.CallParent();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h2>This is Child window</h2> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

You should not do this on the parent, otherwise opener.CallParent() will not work, doing window.CallParent makes CallParent available as window scope:

```
function CallParent() {
  alert(" Parent window Alert");
}
```

And then you can simply call `opener.CallParent();` not `window.opener.CallParent();`.

Comment: Try this: `window.parent.CallParent();`

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code
**parent.html**

```
<html> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CallParent()
        {
            alert(" Parent window Alert");
        }
    </script>
    <body> 
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" NAME="My Window Name" title=" My title here " onClick=window.open("child.html","Ratting","width=550,height=170,0,status=0,");>Click here to open the child window</a>
    </body> 
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
           window.opener.CallParent();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h2>This is Child window</h2> 
    </body> 
</html>
```