# Refresh a php page after response from window page

Tags: javascript, php, window, refresh

I am opening a new window from main.php after click on button.
Details are displayed into open window details.php.
I update the details into that window.
I want refresh a main.php page when window get closed.
How can we get response from details.php to main.php?

Comment: Make an Ajax call from you details.php to main.php... Or write your code so that we can give some other suggestions according to your code..

Answer (score 0):

Make a reload JS function in the parent window and call it from child window before closing it. Guide to achieve it is here [How to call parent window function from child window jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098573/how-to-call-parent-window-function-from-child-window-jquery)