# Aurelia framework update model from javascript callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, aurelia

I'm trying to migrate a piece of code from plain JavaScript to `Aurelia`, and I can't seem to figure out the following code (executed from within a view-model):

```
var callbackFunction = 'DmsToWorkflowsCallback';
var treeEnum = new BrowseTreeNodeEnums();
var contentType = treeEnum.Document;
var url = dmsUrlPrefix + 
          "BrowseDlgEx.aspx?" + 
          "multiSelect=1" + 
          "&title=Attach" + 
          "&callback=" + callbackFunction + 
          "&contentType=" + contentType + 
          "&context=btworkflows;" + domain;
window.open(url, "_blank", "height=600, width=800,status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=no,modal=1,dialog=yes,top=100,left=100");
```

In plain JavaScript, the calling window (which is a custom plugin with no documentation) was able to locate the callback function (line 1) and execute the rest of the business logic correctly; in Aurelia, however, it doesn't seem able to locate the provided function!

I tried specifying the callback function both inside and outside the class (using regular function declaration), as well as using `this.DmsToWorkflowsCallback` as the callback function specification, without success...

I even tried adding a dummy callback function inside the View using a `<script>` tag, but still couldn't even get a break-point to hit!

If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What does your Aurelia code look like?

Comment: @AshleyGrant I'm calling the above code from a simple Aurelia click.delegate="..." function in my ViewModel, and what I'm trying to do is catch the window.open's returning callback.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797560/set-a-callback-function-to-a-new-window-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the callback function on the `window` object. If the function you want to call is a function on your VM, then it would be best to wrap the call in a fat arrow function:

```
window.theCallback = () => this.theCallback();
window.open('http://localhost:9000/foo.html', '_blank');
```

Then, in the child page, you'll call this function using the `opener` reference.

```
opener.theCallback();
```

Comment: To add a comment, this question is really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098573/how-to-call-parent-window-function-from-child-window-jquery (even though no jQuery is used here). That answer says to use `window.parent`, but I wasn't able to get that to work. Only `window.opener` worked.