# JavaScript: calling function of parent window from child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am opening a popup window from a page. The process goes like this:

```
var newwindow = window.open("mydomain.com/a.html", "Testing", 'height=600,width=800');
if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
```

`mydomain.com/a.html` opens a popup mydomain.com/b.html

`mydomain.com/b.html` redirects the user to another site(say payment gateway) 
`paymentgateway.com/authenticate.html`

`paymentgateway.com/authenticate.html` redirects the user to `mydomain.com/success.html`

From `mydomain.com/success.html` I want to execute a function written on `mydomain.com/a.html`

I have written

```
window.parent.LaunchFunction();
window.close();
```

but it's not working. What can be the issue? Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Pop-ups don't have `parent`, they have `opener`.

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34130841/2702249

Comment: @Teemu, you are right. Using opener worked. Can you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm offering another way - **use the local storage** for communication between apps at the same origin (same protocol+domain+port).

You can add listener, that is fired when somebody change any property in localstorage.

#### First instance is listening

```
window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageChange, false);

function onStorageChange (e) {
  if (e.key === 'messageText') {
    var messageText = localStorage.getItem('messageText');
    if (messageText) { // Prevent to call when fired by `removeItem()` below
      console.log('New message from another instance has come:', messageText);
      localStorage.removeItem('messageText'); // this will fires the `onStorageChange` again.
    }
  }
}
```

#### Second instance is sending the messages

```
localStorage.setItem('messageText', 'Hello from second app instance');
```