# How to call the parent function from a popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function showMap which opens a new window(window.open).In the new window I have a iframe googlemaps and a input with button.How can i pass the data when user clicks the button to a function in the parent window?

```
var popUpWindow ;
function showMap(){
     popUpWindow = window.open(index)
     popUpWindow.document.write( '<html><head><title>MAP</title>
     </head><body>
     <iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?> 
     </iframe> <br> <input type="text" id="data> 
     <button type="button" onclick="opener.callParent()">
      Update</button></body></html');
}

function callParent(){
  var newValue = popUpWindow.document.getElementById('data').value;
  console.log('newVal',newValue);
}
```

Doing in this way i was able to get the value from child window to parent window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call parent window function from child window jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098573/how-to-call-parent-window-function-from-child-window-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `window.opener` global under that new popup

Comment: This is a correct answer, don't know why it's down voted. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 import/export.

To do that firstly export parents function then import it and use in the modal.

Another way, but dangerous one is to use global window scope to implement the method you want to call.

Comment: I want to achieve this in jade. So, i can't import as ES6