# How can Flex application (with-in an IFrame) invoke a JS method from the main page?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

My main page loads an iframe which contains a Flex application (which occupies part of the screen).

The flex app has a "Cancel" button which should make the main page navigate to a different location using a JavaScript method in the main page ("goBack()").

I tried to use this Flex - AS code for the "Cancel" button with no luck (it tried to invoke JS function using the parent object):

```
    public function cancel(){
        flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("parent.goBack()");
    }
```

This is the JavaScript code

```
   function goBack(){
          window.top.location='some_URL';
   }
```

Appreciate your thoughts

**Update:**

i find out I get the following error when trying to invoke the JS method:

```
     "Blocked a frame with origin https://SITEA from accessing a cross-origin frame."
```

Comment: This should be simple - make sure the main page and your iframe page are both loaded from the same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen there are a lot of limitations when trying to invoke JS methods between different origins (for instance, iframes from different domains/ports).

I bypass the issue by using the IFrame-Flex app to call the main page "history->back" method:

```
          flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("window.history.back()");
```

That is working fine.

I also noticed that there is a special library for communications between different origins called easyxdm

http://easyxdm.net/wp/

I didn't use it, but it get lots of community endorsement.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function), you're on the right track for calling your main page `goBack()` function.

Try adding a javascript function to your iframe-loaded page:

```
function iframeGoBack() {
    window.parent.goBack();
}
```

Then call that from `ExternalInterface`

Alternatively, if you know the desired URL, you could switch to using `navigateToURL()` inside your Flex code.

Comment: Unfortunately using window.parent is not working.
I don't see navigateToLocation, I tried to use navigateToURL but it change the iframe URL and I need to change the main page URL

Comment: Oops, I meant navigateToURL.  If you `alert(window.parent);` in your iframe, what do you see?

Comment: I have the URL to navigate to, I have an issue with directing the main page to this URL from my IFrame