# Close a popup modal window of iframe type through a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have a parent page and child page sharing the same **file.js** file for *jquery* events.

Well I am working with `Magnific Popup` and I have:

```
$("#addDetailButton").magnificPopup({
        items: {
              src: 'someURL'
        },
        type: 'iframe',
        enableEscapeKey: false,
        modal: true

});
```

My popup is based on `iframe` and is `modal`. How I can close the modal window with a `button` html element? I did a research on StackOverflow and all the replies and based in `inline` type.

I have tried

```
<input id="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel"/> // child page

$("#cancel").click(function(){
        $.magnificPopup.close();
});
```

and I always receive trough Firefox's Web Console the following:

```
TypeError: $.magnificPopup is undefined
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Iframe has its own scope it can't access the surrounding scope directly. But you can step up in the main window with the parent global variable.

Try this:

```
parent.$.magnificPopup.close();
```

You can find more on this topic here: [Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function)