# Phonegap/Cordova: Call a function from a button inside iframe

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, iframe

I have an iframe opening in my application, I want to open a particular application page (say chat window) from a button inside that iframe but as I need to send some data to that page too, I have to call a function. Iframe have the page hosted on our website. Can we have control from iframe pages to application? Can we launch a mobile app from browser?

I am using jQuery mobile and PhoneGap both latest version. **Here is my page** and *for example I want to go to welcome page or want to open a chat window which is a functionality in my app from inside iframe which is a aspx page*:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme='b' data-dom-cache="false" class="demo-page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <iframe id="page-src" src="http://mywebsite/page.aspx" width="100%" height="100%" class="bootstrap-iframe"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: postMessage() + addEventListener("message")

Comment: Sorry but didn't get you.

Comment: Can you add some code explaining what you're doing? Otherwise it is unclear.

Comment: @JuanCarlosFarah, is it clear now? Just wants to check possibility.

Comment: I have very much doubt that it will be possible. There is some cross domain security issues. your best chance I guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe window.parent. call a function of parent with `parent.func()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
Call

```
parent.postMessage('msg','*');
```

from inside iframe.

you can get this event in your page using-

```
window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
   alert(event.data); // call function here
},false);
```

Can add conditions accordingly data you get from iframe.

Comment: This will not work as you post a message of type "msg" while you listen to a message of type "message". Those two must match for this to work.