# click in iframe link load website in the master page not only in the iframe

Tags: html, iframe

If  I have a web page with a iframe and that iframe has a link, can I load the webpage with the link iframe?

pageMaster.html:

```
<iframe src="pageDetail.html">
```

Comment: The title tells more than the actual question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe

Comment: yes, its possible. Just set the top frame location to the url needed.