# when its click on image inside iframe, can popup be shown outside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have iframe inside another page. when clicked on image inside iframe, the popup will appears inside iframe. I need popup to show outside iframe.can I do this from css?

Comment: welcome to SO. Please, take your time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - help us help you! you can edit your question afterwards or post another one if this one gets closed.

Comment: i think that it cant be done by using just css

Answer (score 1):

Not with CSS, but it should be possible using JavaScript if that's any use?

[Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe)