# Uncaught reference error after calling javascript method

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to extract data from the result of a submission of a form, that is located inside an `iFrame` using injected `javascript`.

I do this by using a `mouseover` event that activates when the current element is a link and has a particular id.

However, when calling the function submitAction_win0:

```
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form'); 
    submitAction_win0(forms[0],nameOfSomething);
```

I get

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: submitAction_win0 is not defined".

However when I click "View Frame Source" I can find:

```
    function submitAction_win0(form, name){
       //some code
    }
```

located in the head before the body.

I also used `document.body.innerHTML` to verify if I was looking at the right page and I got the same body HTML.

EDIT: tried putting parent before the function:

```
    parent.submitAction_win0(forms[0],nameOfSomething);
```

And I received this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: parent.submitAction_win0 is not a function"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a parent window function from an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe)

Comment: I saw that one and tried it before posting this, didn't work

Comment: Still sounds like it could be a scope issue. Post an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Any answer to your current question would just be a guess.