# Jquery calling function of parent from iframe

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, function, iframe

I have a dashboard page.. and a `loadfile()` function in its `dashboard.js` file.
I have an iframe in the dashboard which is `addsite.html` with `addsite.js` file..

I need to call `loadfile()` from `addsite.js`..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Import `dashboard.js` in `addsite.html`, and then call it's `loadfile()` method.

For example:

```
<script src="dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="addsite.js"></script>

<!-- ... more markup ... -->
```

Now, in `addsite.js`, you can access `dashboard.js`' functions.

Comment: i cant..because the `loadfile()` is used to load a file into the parent document's div. so icant do that from iframe.

Comment: Why are you using `iframes` anyway? It's a bad practice. You want an `iframe` to modify its parent's div?

Comment: Its used in node-webkit application.. I know its a bad practice. but still i have to use it..

Comment: That is impossible. It's like saying that you want to modify Google's homepage from Facebook's URL.