# Call Parent Javascript from Iframe Code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, iframe

I checked [Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe) but it didn't work for me. I want to call parent page `javascript` function from Code behind of a page inside an `iframe`.

**Page Inside Iframe Code**

```
  Protected Sub btnContinue_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnContinue.Click

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "StartTimer", "parent.initializeClock();", True)
  End Sub
```

It is not working. How should I call this from code behind. It must be called from code behind.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you have an error? Are both of your pages on the same domain?

Comment: pages are on the same domain. The function is not calling

Comment: What does "not calling" mean? Does it appear in the view source? Does the browser tries it call it? It parent null? Is initializeClock null? Does it go in initializeCock but the code there isn't working? Is it the RegisterStartupScript that isn't being called?

Comment: I checked in Firebug. It not invoking the function.