# Sending JS variable data from iframe to parent

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, iframe

I am pretty sure i know the answer to this, though i am hoping some one will have a solution. I have a main page which is done mostly in javascript to avoid refreshes, delays etc... I am needing a hidden iframe which automatically refreshes and sends data (variables/arrays) to the parent window for changes to the parent data. Is this possible? or is there a better solution which i am not aware of?

Preferably in Javascript, as i have not got my head around JQuery yet.

Before admins start asking for coding, there is no trial coding for this yet (which the exception of a semi blank iframe page) because i am unsure on where to start!!

Comment: Sure it's possible but you really haven't outlined what the use case is for this iframe for anyone to offer alternatives of which there are several. Have a read through [ask] then try to edit question to make it a lot more specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe

Comment: Better solutions ... Without an iframe, with AJAX on the main page?