# Calling A Javascript Function in a Parent Window from a link inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, function, iframe

I've got a parent page and a child page issue involving JavaScript functions back and forth. The basic idea (this is for a menu system on a mobile site for thousands of pages of content) is that there is a NAV on the parent page which is hidden using CSS (z-index) which has an iFrame in it. On the body of the parent page is a button which performs two JavaScript functions: it swaps the z-index to display the NAV over the body and it loads the child page into the iFrame in the NAV. This is all working well.

My issue is that I have another button in the NAV and the function that performs is to re-hide the NAV (send the z-index back to its hidden location). I want to get rid of this button and have the iFrame take up the entire NAV, and then I want to have a button on the child page which calls the same function to reset the z-index.

Basically, you see a blank page with a button, you hit the button and a NAV window appears with content loaded in an iFrame. And in this iFrame is a button to make the NAV disappear and again just show a black page with the first button.

I scoured over the site and googled this several times but I'm a JavaScript novice and I can't quite figure out how to make the button on the child page call the JavaScript function on the parent page. I followed some of the suggestions made on this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe), but all I get now is that the button on the child page make the parent disappear and loads the child page in the browser (not what I was going for).

Here's the CSS & HTML/JAVASCRIPT on the Parent Page:

```css
/*Basic Style*/
 body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: tahoma;
  text-wrap: suppress;
 }
/*End: Basic Style*/ 
 
/*Pop Out Menu Styles*/
.PopOutMenu {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.PopOutMenu-Top {
 top: -2000px;
}
.PopOutMenu-Top.PopOutMenu-Open {
 top: 0px;
}
.PopOutMenu,
.PopOutMenu-push {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
/*End Menus*/
 
/*Header*/
#header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 7%;
 background-color: blue;
 display: table;
 position: fixed;
 padding-top: 1%;
 padding-bottom: 1%;
 text-align: center;
}

#showChild {
 font-family: tahoma;
 font-size: 4vw;
 line-height: 1.6875;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: inherit;
 background-color: #0F9600;
 width: 30vw;
}
#showChild:active {
 background-color: darkgreen;
}
#MenuContainer {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
 padding-top: 100%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#MenuContainer iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 101%;
    height: 100%;
 border: 0;
}
/*End Header*/

.BackButton {
 background-color: red;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ButtonSwap-4</title>

<script>
function loadFrame (elm){
    var frame1 = document.getElementById('menuframe');
    frame1.src = elm.dataset.src;
}
</script>
<link href="parent-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<nav class="PopOutMenu PopOutMenu-Horizontal PopOutMenu-Top" id="PopOutMenu-1">
 <div class="BackButton">    <button id="closeNAV">
   X
  </button>
 </div>

 <div id="MenuContainer">
  <iframe id="menuframe"></iframe>
 </div>

</nav>

<div id="header">
 <button id="showChild" data-src="child.html"> Open NAV</button>
</div>





<script src="../../../../js/classie.js"></script>
<script>
closeNAV.onclick = function() {
 classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
 classie.toggle( menuTop, 'PopOutMenu-Open' );
 disableOther( 'closeNAV' );
};
function disableOther( button ) {
 if( button !== 'closeNAV' ) {
  classie.toggle( closeNAV, 'disabled' );
 }
}
 
var menuTop = document.getElementById( 'PopOutMenu-1' ),
 showChild = document.getElementById( 'showChild' ),
 body = document.body;
showChild.onclick = function() {
 classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
 classie.toggle( menuTop, 'PopOutMenu-Open' );
 disableOther( 'showChild' );
 loadFrame(this);
};
function disableOther( button ) {
 if( button !== 'showChild' ) {
  classie.toggle( showChild, 'disabled' );
 } 
}


</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS & HTML/JAVASCRIPT for the child:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#ChildContainer {
 display: table;
 background-color: green;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="ChildContainer">
 <a href="#" id="closeNAV" onclick="window.top.disableOther( button ) {
 if( button !== 'closeNAV' ) {
  classie.toggle( closeNAV, 'disabled' );">Close NAV</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be hot. Thank you!

Note: the javascript for this was created using [Codrops blueprint for Slide & Push Menus.](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/)

Comment: what errors do you see in the developer tools console

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: to be honest the "code" looks odd ... even trying to interpret what you meant to do,  why would "button" ever not be "closeNav" - seeing as the code is "attached" to the closeNav button? I dont' understand the purpose of the if condition at all ... but the main problem is, the code ... `somefunction(argument) { ... code ...}` is not valid syntax (generally, there is a case where it is)

Comment: Yeah, 'the "code" looks odd ...' is understandable. As I said, I'm a novice for Javascript and I basically took the blueprint from codrops for what I wanted the NAV element to do (be hidden but then appear at an onclick) and cleaned out every bit of code I didn't need until I was left which just the bit that works. So, I'd expect it isn't written in a clean and clear-cut way.

Comment: That being said, this is for a project for a text book app. The idea is that each chapter of the book will be a parent page with a fixed header for navigation. In the navigation the user hits button or link to show the hidden NAV element and depending on which button they hit (Chapter or  Section) a different HTML object will load in the iFrame to further navigate. Then they can either hit the navigation link to go to a different chapter or section of the book OR they can hit a close button to hide the NAV again and go back to where they were. Does that help?