# Unable to call a function nor postMessage inside an Iframe with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

Helly everyone,

I desperately try to call a function inside an Iframe for hours without success.

Here are the two things I have (working on Safari), the parent code:

```
window.frames['map-frame'].Test();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('map-frame').contentWindow.postMessage("test", '*');
```

The frame code:

```
window.Test = function ()
 {
  alert("1");
 }
```

or

```
window.receiveMessage = function (event)
{
  alert("2");
}
addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);
```

As I said, it works for both solutions in Safari, but not in Chrome. Both files are on my webserver (I've seen that local calls can be blocked in Chrome). I've tried barely anything I've found on Stackoverflow and Google but nothing do the tricks.

Did anyone ever has the same issue? Anyone knows a tricks or something to try?

Thanks in advance folks

Comment: When you use postMessage API you don't need to go inside the iframe to do the `post`

Comment: maybe `addEventListener("message", receiveMessage);` change it to `window.addEve....` not sure where you have that method call

Comment: @charlietfl: What do you mean by no need to go inside the iframe?

Comment: @UXDart: Thanks for help, I've tried, still not working

Comment: Meaning you call 'post` in one window and receive in another

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40407241/3316068

This solution from William Littlefield worked for me. Also, make sure your frame is fully loaded before calling a function from it.