# How an iframe button can call function on parent

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have seen many answers for this on stackoverflow but none will work.  Should be simple.  A button in an `<iframe>` calling a function on parent.

Button and function on `<iframe>`

```
<script>
function back(){
   parent.test();

}
</script>

<button type="button" onClick="back()">BACK</button>
```

Function on parent window:

```
<script>
function test() {
        alert("I worked!");
    }
</script>
```

Things that I thought might be causing a problem, NONE are I tested:

- The parent window is HTML
- `<iframe>` is PHP
- This is the 2nd iframe loaded in that orig parent iframe

I have made sample test that work perfect.  Having an iframe load another iframe.  Still able to call parent function.  Posistion of function is right above `<body>` tag on parent page and right below BTN on `<iframe>` page.

All live and test files are on the same server.  Something within other code on my live site must be effecting it, just have no idea what.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe)

Comment: A little dif title. Though I have seen and tried this one an still not working