# Call function on parent iframe with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, iframe

Im trying to accomplish the same as what is explained on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe) but in ReactJS. Which is calling a function that belongs to the parent from the page contained in the iframe, passing also parameters from the child to the parent.

So far I have in the parent page:

```
handleClickOnParent(someParams){
    alert("My son clicked!"+someParams);
}
```

In the page contained in the iframe, the following:

```
handleClick(){
    window.parent.handleClickOnParent(localParameters)
}
render(){
    return(
        <button onClick = {() => { this.handleClick() }}>Click me</button>
    );
}
```

From which I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.handleClickOnParent is not a function

How can I call a function that is only available on the parent. I also tried passing the function as a prop, but it's not accesible from the iframe page, because it's not a component, it's a frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `<iframe>` inside a Component, and then pass the function as a prop, something like:

```
class IFrameComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
     <iframe onClick={this.props.handleFunction}>
   }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
<IFrameComponent handleFunction={this.handlingFunction} />
```

Comment: but I need that the page loaded in the iframe makes the call, because it will contain some parameters that I want to pass on to the parent.