# Is it possible to access a array that is outside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

The problem is this: inside my main page (`parent.html`) I have an iframe (`child.html`) and a script block. In that script block there is a array of integers and a function that adds elements to the list. In the iframe there is a new function that adds an element to the list of the main file (`parent.html`).

I would like to know if it is possible for the iframe (`child.html`) to access this function found in `parent.html`. Example:

**parent.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent</title>
        <script>
            var parentList = [0];
            var counter = 0;

            function addValue(){
                counter++;
                parentList.push(counter);
                console.log('parent', parentList);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="addValue()">Add Value (Parent)</button>
        <br />
        <iframe src="child.html" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**child.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Child</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="addValueInternal()">Add Value Child</button>
        <script>
            var internalCount = 0;

            function addValueInternal() {
                internalCount++;
                parentList.push(internalCount);
                console.log('child', parentList);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The error**:

```
child.html:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: parentList is not defined
    at addValueInternal (child.html:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (child.html:6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. it is possible. Based on an example [calling a function defined in the parent from an embedded iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2161388/6691953).

So in your case, you would have to reference the `parent` when accessing your array.

```
function addValueInternal() {
  internalCount++;
  parent.parentList.push(internalCount); // here we access the reference
  console.log('child', parentList);
}
```

Be aware that you may encounter problems concerning the cross-origin policy afterwards.