# Vuejs recieve event from iframe using postmessage

Tags: javascript, vue.js

according to this topic [Calling a parent window function from an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe)

Say that iframe can send data back to parent window.

Now I implement it using vuejs and my code is

```
<v-card>
   <iframe :src="url" style="width:100%; height:100vh; border:0px;"></iframe>
</v-card>
```

and in iframe url I put the script  like

```
$('#uploadbtn').bind("click",function(){
     window.parent.postMessage({
       'func': 'parentFunc',
        'message': 'Message text from iframe.'
     }, "*");
});
```

when user click button it will send message back to parent (vue component).

My question is how can I write code in VueJS side to get message from iframe?

Thank you

Answer (score 15):

You would need to attach an event listener on the `window` for *message* events.

For example (in your component)

```js
methods: {
  receiveMessage (event) {
    console.log(event.data)
  }
},
mounted () {
  window.addEventListener('message', this.receiveMessage)
},
beforeDestroy () {
  window.removeEventListener('message', this.receiveMessage)
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#The_dispatched_event