# Aspx Javascript function not called from other javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radwindow

I worked in .net application, in this application from one aspx page to call one html page through **iframe** and called webservice through JS function. in this html file have button and on this click event I want to call popup window in aspx javascript through another js function. here is code

on html page

```
 <div id="dropArea">
    <button type="button" runat="server" onclick="Test()"> clickme </button>

</div>
```

JS file function

```
    function Test() {
    Config('123', '567');   
}
```

this config function exists in aspx page

aspx page code

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" Skin="Black" Modal="True" ReloadOnShow="True" ShowContentDuringLoad="False" VisibleStatusbar="False" EnableShadow="True" Overlay="True" EnableViewState="False">
     <Windows>
             <telerik:RadWindow ID="ConfigRadWindow" runat="server" Width="750" Height="500" VisibleOnPageLoad="false" Behaviors="Move,Resize,Close" IconUrl="images/icoPhraseTranslationManager.png" Title="Configure" />
    </Windows>
  </telerik:RadWindowManager>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Config(testID, UnitID) {
    var oWnd = radopen("Config.aspx?ID=" + testID + "&UnitID=" + UnitID, "ConfigRadWindow");
  }
</script>
```

I am able to call aspx page with use window.open function but requirement is that to call this Config()function through js function.

P.S. :- I put reference of JS file in aspx page and master page and give me error in console is 'config.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: Config is not defined
at config (VM84 config.js:7)'

Appreciate your help and  Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't mention any specific errors or problems? What goes wrong? But one obvious thing to note is that JS is case-sensitive. `Config` != `config` . Correct that any you may have better luck.

Comment: Apart from that, it looks like it should work as long as the JS file is included in the aspx file (preferably after the script block which includes the definition of the Config function). Or just put them both into the JS file...there seems no obvious reason not to do so. If you continue to have issues though, please check your browser's Console for errors.

Comment: @ADyson: thanks for your comment. As your suggestion I edited my Q again and i did as you suggest to put js file reference in aspx page and even put master page also but still it not work and it show the error in console is 'config.js:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: Config is not defined
    at config (VM84 config.js:7)'. Kindly suggest. Thanks

Comment: Did you try putting both functions inside the JS file? There seems no reason for them to be separate.

Comment: @ADyson:- That I can't do that to put both function inside of js file because 'function Config(testID, UnitID)' used telerik property i.e. "ConfigRadWindow"  to call another aspx page.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. If the JS file is then included into the page, it will still know about that.

Comment: @ADyson:- when i do that it give me 'Uncaught ReferenceError: radopen is not defined' error massage on console. Is am i missing some reference of this function ? please give some idea on that.

Comment: As long as you include your .js file in the page _after_ the `RadWindowManager` control then I doubt there should be a problem. When you're loading things into a HTML document, the order you load them in is important.

Comment: @ADyson:- I will give the order of load. Here is Main.aspx  page which load first and in the middle of page I defined <iframe>. with the use of this , application move to html page. Now what i will try to call function which defined in the last of aspx page which i mention in Q,  on click event of this html page.

Comment: That's the first time you've mentioned using an iframe. It's an important detail. You can't just call a function in the parent page directly from the child page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/calling-a-parent-window-function-from-an-iframe

Comment: @ADyson:- well i mention about iframe in my Q 2nd line, but anyway you give me right direction to how call my function. That given link help me a lot. Thank you very much your time and valuable solution.

Comment: Oh sorry I totally missed that. Apologies. You're right to edit and make it bold!